# Shorthand ternary operator PHP - Call to a member function on null

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Given the class:

```
<?php
class foo {
    public function getGuest() {
        return new guest();
    }
}

class guest {
    public function getGender() {
        return 'F';
    }
}
```

I wanted to refactor the following which works fine:

```
$bar->getGuest() ? $bar->getGuest()->getGender() : NULL
```

To:

```
$bar->getGuest() ?: $bar->getGuest()->getGender()
```

Where I get the error: **Call to a member function getGender() on null**

I was expecting this to work in the same fashion as the top version, as it was my understanding that the second version was, if the left hand side is truthy, return the left-hand, otherwise return the right-hand.  So if the left-hand is falsey, why is the right-hand running?  Can someone explain this?

Given the second version doesn't work, is the top version the most concise?

Comment: The first example does not work fine - it's just you're being protected from the error because the condition never resolves to true, hence the left side of the ternary condition never runs. `getGender()` is not a method of `null`, which is what `getGuest()` returns.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified a little for the sake of the question, in reality, there's a case where getGuest is not null and `getGuest()->getGender()` runs fine.  But if getGuest IS null, then I want to return NULL

Comment: So please update the question to include all pertinent code, including the full definitions for `getGuest()` and `getGender()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/operators.comparison):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Let's look at what you're trying to do here:

```
$bar->getGuest() ?: $bar->getGuest()->getGender()
```

The way this works is if the first `$bar->getGuest()` expression equals `true`, your operation will return the value of `$bar->getGuest()` itself. This should work fine, no errors.

However, if `$bar->getGuest()` returns something else (e.g. `null`) it will run the third expression, which is `$bar->getGuest()->getGender()`.

Well we already established that `$bar->getGuest()` returned `null`, so how can you then go and run another method `->getGender()` on the null value? You can't, which is why you are getting the error.

---

There's nothing wrong with keeping your code readable and simple. You probably want to store the initial method call value, so you don't have to call it again just to run `getGender()`.

```
$guest = $bar->getGuest();
$gender = ($guest === null) ? null : $guest->getGender();
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, the left-hand would be falsey when it's null so it would try and run the right-hand!  My unfamiliarity with the syntax, thanks.  Is the top version still the most concise in that case (PHP 7.4)?